# Font extensions does not work for JasperReports

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports

I am trying to add Tahoma font to jasper report in my web app. I use [font extension mechanism](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions).

This exception was thrown: 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'TahomaFont' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.

Here is my font.xml file:

```html
<fontFamiles>
  <fontFamily name="TahomaFont">
    <normal>export/fonts/BTahoma.ttf</normal>
    <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
    <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
  </fontFamily>
<fontFamiles>
```

and here is my jasperreports.properties file :

```html
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.simple.font.families=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.TahomaFont=export/fonts/fonts.xml
```

Also  i have put Tahoma.ttf font file in my classpath. 
Here is the style tag in jasper report:

```html
<style fontName="TahomaFont" name="tahoma"/>
```

Please let me know where i am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Putting the Tahoma.ttf font in your class path is **not** the way to go.

You are right to use font extensions, it's a good practice - but you need to package your fonts as font extension, into a jar and add that jar to your classpath.

- In jasperReport, manage your fonts, in *options*, in the *Font* tab, select the font and click *export as extension*.
- Package your jar and things should work fine without having to install the physical font on the JVM.

More information documented [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to copy your jar file to your java_home/fonts directory. and if you are usinng maven project you have to package your jar file within a maven project with pom properties to add dependency to pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

You put "Tahoma.ttf" font file in classpath, but declare "BTahoma.ttf" in fonts.xml

```
<normal>export/fonts/BTahoma.ttf</normal>
```

Let's change them to the same.
I think that exception will be disappea.