# Font extensions maven project does not work for JasperReports

Tags: java, maven, fonts, jasper-reports

Don't mark duplicate with this question: [Font extensions does not work for JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274197/font-extensions-does-not-work-for-jasperreports). It's a different case, I'm using a maven project apart.

I am trying to add Open Sans font to jasper report in my web app. I use [font extension mechanism](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions).

> **This exception was thrown:**
>
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font "Open
>   Sans " is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.

**I'm creating a maven project to generate the font-extension:**

Here is my font.xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>
    <fontFamily name="Open Sans">
        <normal><![CDATA[fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf]]></normal>
        <bold><![CDATA[fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Bold.ttf]]></bold>
        <italic><![CDATA[fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Italic.ttf]]></italic>
        <boldItalic><![CDATA[fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf]]></boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding><![CDATA[Identity-H]]></pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts/>
    </fontFamily>
</fontFamilies>
```

and here is my **jasperreports_extension.properties** file :

```html
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.fonts=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.opensans=fonts/fonts.xml
```

Also, I have put *Open Sans* ttf files in a folder named **OpenSans**.

Finally, I added the dependency, this way, to my final project (where it executes the report properly)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myfonts</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfont</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

For some reason, my report can't show the font correctly. Please let me know where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you package the fonts as with the resulting Jar from Maven?

Comment: In the exception message there's a space after the font name (Font "Open Sans " is not available).  Check your JRXML and remove the space after the font name.

Comment: Thank you! You're correct, I removed the space and it works perfectly